# How to write a switch statement inside a method

Tags: android

I have 7 activities A.B,C,D,E,F,G. When I click any of these buttons, for ex:if i click A, i want to go to that activity. I want to do it in Switch case using a method. I tried doing this,but my app crashed:

What's wrong in this code.Y its crashing?

```
package com.example.assignment2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Act_A extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView text;
    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
        text.setText("This is Activity A");
        text.setTextSize(20);
    }
    public void Display(View v) {
        switch (btn.getId()) {
        case R.id.butA:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Act_A.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.butB:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Act_B.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;
        case R.id.butC:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Act_C.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            break;
        case R.id.butD:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Act_D.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            break;
        case R.id.butE:
            Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, Act_E.class);
            startActivity(intent4);
            break;
        case R.id.butF:
            Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, Act_F.class);
            startActivity(intent5);
            break;
        case R.id.butG:
            Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, Act_G.class);
            startActivity(intent6);
            break;
        }
    }
    public void NextActivity(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Act_B.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void Display(View v) {
    switch (btn.getId()) {

--------------

}

}
```

change **btn.getId()** to **v.getId()**

You are trying to access id of the uninitialized object **btn** you just declared **Button btn**.

Do something like this

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView text;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    text.setText("This is home activity");
    text.setTextSize(20);
}

public void Display(View v) {

    Intent mIntent = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.butA:
        mIntent = new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class);
        break;

    case R.id.butB:
        mIntent = new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);
        break;

    case R.id.butC:
        mIntent = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);
        break;

    case R.id.butD:
        mIntent = new Intent(this, PostsActivity.class);      
        break;
    }

    if(mIntent != null){
        startActivity(mIntent);
    //if you wanted to finish this activity uncomment following line
    //finish();
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {    
    super.onBackPressed();
}

}
```

if you wanted to call an activity and finish the current activity you should call finish method

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
finish();
```

If you wanted to finish the current activity on back button,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {  

//write the functions you need to do before finishing the activity here
// if you written this line **super.onBackPressed();** which finish the activity on back press
   super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Now i want to include that function in all activities...So can i just declare a object of Activity A and access the Display method from other activities, just like how we do in java?

Comment: No you shouldn't do that. Handle button clicks within the activity classes itself, it will be good practice.

Comment: Y so..I mean..its like duplicating the code na..I mean same function i should write in all activities..

Comment: Based on the above code, if you wanted to call the same function from different activities create a separate class ClickHandler or something the create the method Display(View v) in that class, pass context to the constructor of that class then call the method from different acivities

Comment: If you are doing this remember that you are just starting the activities. You must finish the activities somewhere.

Comment: Can u give me some example..I'm a beginner so i dono how to do that

Comment: I think its complex.Ite better to put the method in all activities

Comment: Okay..Then ill put it in every activity.

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing `Button btn;` in `onCreate` so you get `NullPointerException`

If you have declared click listener in xml you should have:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
// cases
}
```

Comment: but i have 7 buttons,so i declared it before on create and used directly in the method..should i declare it inside OnCreate?

Comment: yes you need to to initialize it then only you can use that object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change `btn.getId()` to `v.getId()` in your `switch`

```
public void Display(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your buttons.

```
Button btnA;
```

//

```
btnA= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnA);
```

Also import onclicklistner

```
btnA..setOnClickListener(this);
```

and use switch statement like this

```
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnA:
```

Comment: But i want to write switch inside a method and use that method in different activities? I wrote a method n it worked now..But how to access it from other activities?

Comment: @sangeetha are you playing game by accepting and removing on answers given..With in 2 minutes you have accepted all answers.

Comment: Actually everyone answers is same..So Iws accepting everyones..But I think i can accept only one answer

Comment: When all answers same, the proper action is to accept the answer which was the first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
             public void Display(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btn_A :
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Act_A.class);
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;

               case R.id.btn_B :
                        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Act_B.class);
                        startActivity(intent2);
                        break;
                     case R.id.btn_C :
                        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, Act_C.class);
                        startActivity(intent3);
                        break;
                     case R.id.btn_D :
                        Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, Act_D.class);
                        startActivity(intent4);
                        break;
                     case R.id.btn_E :
                        Intent intent5 = new Intent(this, Act_E.class);
                        startActivity(intent5);
                        break;
                     case R.id.btn_F :
                        Intent intent6 = new Intent(this, Act_F.class);
                        startActivity(intent6);
                        break;
                      case R.id.btn_G :
                        Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, Act_G.class);
                        startActivity(intent7);
                        break;


        }
        }
```

try this, I have not tried yet but i hope it will work...
In Display Method instead of passing View parameter pass int parameter.

```
public void Display(int btn_id)
{
switch (btn_id) {
//same as above
}
}
```

I guess you will write this method in A activity and now
from different activity on click of button B,call this method and send id of button B
as its parameter and see if it works.

Comment: I did that..now i want to use that method in all activities..So I want to write it in one activity and access it from other activities..Is it possible?

Comment: Its possible but it will be better if you go with handling button events in individual activity as it will increase code optimization and good practice

Comment: Okay Ill check..Thanks